# Rotate array and find index of maximum element

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a program where I need to find out the index position of an array which holds the maximum value in that array after doing left rotation of that array.

For example:

If array is {5,7,1,8,2}. This array maximum value as 8. If I rotate the array 2 times then result is 1,8,2,5,7. Then the index position of max element 8 is 1.

If I rotate my array {5,7,1,8,2} by 6 times then array becomes 7,1,8,2,5. The index of 8 now is 2.

My program takes the array and the number of rotations as input and returns an array that contains the index position of max element when the array is rotated.

```
int[] rotate(int[] array, int[] rotate) {
    int[] result = new int[rotate.length];
    int index = 0;
    int large = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > large) {
            large = array[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rotate.length; i++) {
        int r = rotate[i];
        if (index - r < 0) {
            if (r > array.length) {
                r = r % array.length;
                result[i] = index - r;
            } else {
                result[i] = index - (index - r);
            }
        } else {
            result[i] = index - r;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The program works in some cases but fails for other test cases which I am not able to find them.

Can you please help where I did mistake in this code?

Comment: What is input and expected output? Because I think it can be a bit more optimized(and hence can take advantage if test cases are being failed due to time out)

Comment: Do you *actually* have to rotate an array or just find the right index (the former could be done without (physically) rotation?

Comment: @zlakad, I just need to find the indices

Comment: Than, I'm not following the logic... *If I rotate an array 2 times...* violate the method `int[] rotate(int[] array, int[] rotate)` declaration. Should be `int[] rotate(int[] array, int rotate)`?

Comment: I'd concentrate to write the method with this signature `int findIndexOfMaxAfterRotate (int [] arr, int noOfRotation)`

Comment: Can rotations be negative?

Comment: I truly believe that you can find the index of max element in the original array and **then** calculate what is the value of this index after rotation, **without** rotation....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following function. See it working [here](https://ideone.com/Lknu3p):

```
int[] rotate(int[] array, int[] rotate) 
{
    int[] result = new int[rotate.length];
    int index = 0;
    int large = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > large) {
            large = array[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    int len = array.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < rotate.length; i++) {
         int r = (index - (rotate[i]%len));
         result[i] = (r>=0) ? r : (len+r); 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Following is complete code:

```
class Test
{
    static int[] rotate(int[] array, int[] rotate) 
    {
        int[] result = new int[rotate.length];
        int index = 0;
        int large = array[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > large) {
                large = array[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }
        int len = array.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < rotate.length; i++) {
             int r = (index - (rotate[i]%len));
             result[i] = (r>=0) ? r : (len+r); 
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int nums[] = {5,7,1,8,2};
        int r[] = {2, 6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0};

        int res[] = rotate(nums, r);

        for(int i=0; i<res.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(r[i] + " = "+ res[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
2 = 1
6 = 2
5 = 3
1 = 2
2 = 1
3 = 0
4 = 4
5 = 3
0 = 3
```

Comment: Can you please help me to understand this line `int r = (index - (rotate[i]%len)%len);
         result[i] = (r>=0) ? r : (len+r); `

Comment: Line `int r = (index - (rotate[i]%len)%len); ` should be `int r = (index - (rotate[i]%len)); `(though both produce same result). I have updated in answer.

Comment: __Line `int r = (index - (rotate[i]%len));`__, in part `(rotate[i]%len)` I'm trying to calculate actual number of rotations e.g. if there are 5 elements in array, then either I rotate it 3 or 8 or 13 18 or so on... times it will produce the same result. In part `(index - (rotate[i]%len))` I'm trying to get index of maximum element(`index` hold index of maximum element in original array). But this result may be -ve e.g. in case of array{5,8,1,7,2} with 1 rotation. So this being corrected in line `result[i] = (r>=0) ? r : (len+r);`. Hope it is clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the index of the greatest number, your code works

   ```
   int index = 0;
   int large = array[0];
   for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
       if (array[i] > large) {
           large = array[i];
           index = i;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Rotate the array

   ```
   //Rotate the array until the maximum value is the first index
   for (int rotations = 0; rotations < index; rotations++) {
       int temp = rotate[0]; //Store the first value of the array in a temporary value
       for (int i = 1; i < rotate.length; i++) {
           rotate[i - 1] == rotate[i]; //move each value one index to the left, replacing the old value at i with the one next to it
       }
       rotate[rotate.length - 1] = temp; //replace the last index of the array with the stored temp value ("Rotating it left")
   }
   return rotate; //return the new array which is now rotated
   ```

Also note that in java, you do not need to return the array value, you can just pass it into the method, change the values, and the original array will be the same as the one you modified inside of this method. An example of this would be...

```
Arrays.sort(array);
System.out.println(array);
//or
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array));
System.out.println(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams to find the index and then offset it by each rotation:

```
int[] rotate(int[] array, int[] rotate) {
    int len = array.length;

    // find the index of the greatest element
    int index = IntStream.range(0, len)
            .reduce(Integer.MIN_VALUE, (a, b) -> array[a] > array[b] ? a : b);

    // offset the index by each rotation
    return Arrays.stream(rotate)
            .map(r -> (index + len + (r % len)) % len)
            .toArray();
}
```